# A condição do If não esta aceitando em asp.net mvc razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, razor

Quero fazer um update com uma condição, porem, está atualizando os dados sem ver a condição do if

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BlogWeb.ViewsModels;
using BlogWeb.DAO;
using BlogWeb.Models;
using BlogWeb.Filters;
using BlogWeb.Controllers;
using NHibernate;
using BlogWeb.Infra;

namespace BlogWeb.Controllers
{
    public class GerenciamentoKM
    {
        private Rota p;
        private ISession session;
        public GerenciamentoKM(ISession session, Rota p)
        {
            this.p = p;
            this.session = session;
        }
        public void soma (Rota post)
        {
                using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.AbreSession())
                {
                    if (p.Km_Atual <= p.Km_Anterior)
                    {
                        ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();
                        session.Update(post);
                        tx.Commit();
                    }
                 }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Porque você não põe o `if` pra fora do `using`?

Comment: Uma pergunta, você não deveria estar comparando `if(post.Km_Atual > p.Km_Anterior)` pelo que entendi os dados atualizados estão no post que é o objeto sendo salvo correto?

Comment: o post serve para pegar informações da lamba p, oque tentei fazer foi puxar direto do banco, porem não funciona

Comment: Poderia colocar o código onde você instancia a classe GerenciamentoKM? E quais os valores apresentados no p.Km_Atual e no p.Km_Anterior ao debugar?